# How to check if a database table exist in PDO?

Tags: pdo, doctrine-orm, native

Something like this:

```
$connection->executeQuery('check table historial1 in database $connection->executeQuery('show tables')')
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717495/check-if-a-database-table-exists-using-php-pdo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a database table exists using PHP/PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717495/check-if-a-database-table-exists-using-php-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES 'Table_Name' ";
    if($this->is_connected)
    {
        $query = $this->pdo->query($sql);
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
    return FALSE;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.