# How to show all tables of Microsoft Access PDO Object?

Tags: ms-access, pdo, odbc

```
$tdb = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$sdltdbsavedfilename; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
$tdbresult = $tdb->query($sql);
var_dump($tdbresult);
```

Gives:
`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE [42000] : Syntax error or access violation: [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] SQL statement is not correct. Use 'DELETE' 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' OR 'UPDATE'. (SQLPrepare [0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:203)`

What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Try query the system table:

```
$sql = 'Select Name From MSysObjects Where Flags = 0 And Type = 1';
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives: no reading rights for MSysObjects. Cannot read records.

Comment: You may have to be user _Admin_: [Record cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669641/3527297).

Comment: The question is then: how do I become Admin from PHP?

Comment: Just claim that you are. _Admin_ is the default (and for .accdb the only) user.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to claim that from PHP.

Comment: It's the UID, I guess. But I know zero about pdo.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went for this solution instead:

[Check if a database table exists using PHP/PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717495/check-if-a-database-table-exists-using-php-pdo)

So instead of searching all tables, I just try one and check whether it exists before proceeding.